# Живое обновление или как пользоваться WebSocket

Tags: jquery, php, chat, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток.

Я уже просто в отчаянии, я перечитал кучу литературы, пересмотрел кучу видосиков, и знаете что? Я ничего не понял. Одни пишут устанавливай **Node.js**, потом какую-то **MongoDB**, другие через C# пишут какие-то краказяблики. Дело в том, что я уже написал свой **MVC**, движок на PHP, а как я понял, если устанавливать **Node.js** и ту страшную базу данных, то нужно переписывать всю логику, а это значит, что вся моя работа просто коту под одно место, мне такая перспектива не очень.

В общем, расскажите тупенькому, на примере, как сделать живой чат, который будет выводить сообщения сразу по поступлению, без использования **Node.js** и прочей нечисти, или это невозможно? Буду предельно благодарен. Спасибо за внимание. :)

P.S. "Без всякой нечисти" я имею в виду, чтоб участие принимали только php, jQuery, javascript, mysql ну или там другие библиотеки, которые нужно подключать, а не устанавливать и танцевать перед ними с бубном.

Comment: @IamS Все мне знакомые решения взаимодействия websocket-ов с PHP я перечислил [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/392060#392092). Для задач веба (чат, обновление контента, к примеру, колонки новостей) все эти решения подходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим самый обычный сценарий работы PHP. Он получает запрос, обрабатывает его, дальше ему нужно обратиться в базу данных, он обращается и, внимание, ждет ответа. Пока база выполняет поиск, весь сервер стоит и ждет. Ну, может у вас там многопоточность, тогда не весь. Но тем не менее, даже если у вас хорошая база, там настроено кэширование и все, что полагается, увы, если вы прикрутите сокеты к вашему PHP, он, скорее всего, не справится. Конечно, зависит от нагрузки, но вы ведь планируете расширяемое приложение? Обычный пользователь не обновляет страницу с огромной частотой, а вот печатать кучу сообщений или принимать кучу уведомлений — запросто. В целом, нагрузка может увеличиться в разы, даже в десятки. Это специфика сокетов: нам нужно уметь быстро отправлять много легких ответов. PHP слишком тяжел для этого.

Почему все советуют ноду или что-то подобное? Асинхронность. Пока бд отвечает, мы можем обрабатывать другие запросы. Как от бд прийдет ответ — мы вернемся к запросу, породившему обращение в базу. Оно как раз подходит для таких вот штук, когда запросов много. Кроме того, сам по себе сокет — это постоянно открытое соединение, и асинхронность тут как раз кстати.

Конечно, есть много нюансов, и то, что я тут написал, это лишь что-то общее, и по хорошему нужно смотреть на уже существующую архитектуру, думать, как лучше внедрять и все такое.

Теперь про то, как с этим жить дальше. Можно, конечно, пытаться прикручивать все именно к центральному серверу, но если мои доводы, приведенные выше, убедительны, можно пойти другими путями. Я делал так: рядом с основным тяжелым сервером поднимается легкий серверочек, который обрабатывает исключительно сокеты. Он может быть устроен как угодно, у меня там был python + tornado, к примеру. Ну так вот, все дело в том, что общаться с основным сервером ему не особенно нужно. У вас есть что-то, что идет через сокеты. Чатик ли это, или поток видео, не суть. Главное, что оно идет только через сокеты. А основной сервер рендерит странички, делает какую-то логику. И если не смешивать одно с другим, все будет хорошо. Нужно просто четко осознавать, за что у вас отвечают сокеты, а за что — основной сервер. Ну а если уж очень нужно, можно наладить общение с ними, какие-то сигналы.

Comment: @Zelta, тобишь node вытеснит php и уже, попросту, не стоит продолжать изучение php и вообще на нем ничего не стоит делать в масштабных формах?

Comment: @IamS, это совершенно разные инструменты. И цели у них разные. Врятли nodejs вытеснит php. Конечно часть задач, которые лучше выполнять на ноде туда и уедут. Но им там и место.

Comment: @dimka3210, спасибо, это все, что я хотел услышать)